# Practical solution for level-shifting high-signal-count synchronous parallel bus between 5 V TTL CPU and 3.3 V LVTTL FPGA?

Tags: level-shifting

I'm looking for a solution for 5 V<->3.3 V bidirectional level shifting between a CPU with a 5 V TTL-compatible interface (Motorola 88110 bus: ~144 signals with 40-50 MHz clock) and an FPGA with a 3.3 V LVTTL-compatible interface.

From what I've read, it seems that an NMOS bus switch is ideal for this application. It seems that NMOS bus switch ICs capable of level shifting numerous (24-32) signals between 5 V and 3.3 V were once common and cheap (perhaps as recently as a few years ago), but are now mostly obsolete/unavailable, except for perhaps one relatively expensive (>$3.00USD) Texas Instruments part that I've found.

Is there any way to solve this problem using a few economically-priced (<$1.00USD) parts in 2024? Is there a better/modern alternative to the old 24-bit NMOS bus switch ICs?

Or is this just one of those things that you can no longer easily accomplish now that the world has moved on to low-voltage serial buses?

Comment: Are there direction control signals? What length of bus, and impedance? (Mainly, is it short, and CMOS-leveled?) Is this bus consistent with any standard (e.g. QBUS?), or bespoke? In any case, I'm afraid you probably won't get much traction here; types and families of parts come and go as products are introduced and dropped, so any such answers tend to be short-lived / age poorly, and are therefore discouraged.

Comment: Which bus? If you are talking about e.g. ISA bus of PCs, then say so.

Comment: For what it’s worth I don’t think the prohibition on discussions about specific parts makes a lot of sense. Had I found old discussions about the parts I spent hours investigating, it would’ve helped me, at least to understand the historical context and whether they are obsolete, and perhaps provide leads on possible alternatives.

Comment: @TimWilliams There are no simple direction control signals, so I'm planning to use none. The levels are standard 5V TTL. Length is around 3.2 inches max, each side of the level shifter. It’s the Motorola 88110 bus (like PowerPC 60x-bus). 32 address signals, 64 data signals + 8 parity, the rest are clock, control/status, a few IRQ lines & reset signal.

Comment: @Justme Please see above comment.

Answer (score 1):

From the [88110 electrical specifications](http://praxibetel.org/reference/motorola/MC88110EC_D-preliminary.pdf), the interface looks like an ordinary CMOS_33, just 5V tolerant ("TTL compatible"). The switching point relative to CLK is defined at 1.4V, drive HIGH is 20mA at 2.4V, drive LOW is also 20mA at 0.5V, i.e. symmetrical. I would say that old Xilinx FPGAs with GPIO configured for LVCMOS33 and drive strength for 16 mA will be direct match to 88110 signaling, and you don't need any level shifters.

However, if the direct connect does not work for some reason, devices based on Transmission Gate technology (simple FET transistor) like [LSF0108](https://www.ti.com/logic-voltage-translation/voltage-translators-level-shifters/products.html#1512=LSF&) might be good for this job.

Comment: Interesting. Is this assuming 5V is supplied to the 88110 as in the AN1217 reference design? One thing to note is if I take out the level shifters the trace length on a single segment will be about twice as long.

Comment: @E000R Per 88110 specs, these levels/loads are for Vdd=5V if I read the spec correctly. Do you see the specs? Not sure what do you mean about segments and trace length.

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I thought, but just wanted to make sure I understood. Re: trace lengths I meant that in the original design I had the level-shifting bus switch in the middle between the CPU and FPGA, with around 3.2” max trace length on each side. I had originally naively assumed that might help me not have to worry much about transmission line effects, due to the relatively short trace length on each side of the IC (5V and 3.3V bus segments), though I now suspect that may have been misguided.

Comment: @E000R, generally speaking, the 88110 is fabricated in CMOS technology, so there should be no doubt that GPIO cells are anything else. At 50MHz rate and 3" trace the transmission line effects are nearly negligible, but it is still better to equalize the trace length and keep trace impedances in check.

Comment: Sounds good. My concern was that if I remove the bus switch, then the trace lengths between devices will probably be greater than 6.5 inches.

Comment: @E000R, the 88110 bus has certain requirements for setup and hold times, and clock forwarding is not used. So you need to keep propagation times in check, 150-180ps/inch, or more than 1 ns. Any circuitry in between just adds a delay, which you would not want.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: You’re saying you expect the 88110 outputs are actually at 3.3V LVTTL levels despite no max Voh being specified? Should this be fine with a modern FPGA supporting 3.3V IO like the Artix-7?

Comment: @E000R, you are doing some retro-computing with a long-dead MCU. GPIO models do not exist for 88110. Scattered bits of info (like "CLK signal is expected to swing from 0.5 to 2.4V") indicate that the bus is not like full-swing CMOS_5V or CMOS-18V. The bus has tight timing requirements. You might need to design traces for, say, 100 Ohm, and include series resistors at both ends of the trace, or even more complex network, and probably do a lot of experiments before it will work. You might want to check the original interface components for their drive characteristics. I wish you good luck.

Comment: Yes, that has been my concern. I believe most systems back in the day used custom ASICs, so there were few standard interface ICs besides the MC88915 clock driver and MCM62110 dual-port SRAM used with the 88410. AN1217 presents a system design using discrete components and a few PALs, with relatively long trace lengths (>11 inches IIRC), but it does not give any specifics of the termination ICs that are shown in the schematics. Similar designs like the PowerMac 9600 used RC termination network ICs that are no longer manufactured.

Comment: I’ve been meaning to do this project for 15 years but it’s looking like I may have waited too long. Anyway, thanks for your advice. It’s greatly appreciated.